# iOS: How to remove the grey bar on the sides?

Tags: ios, webview, view, uiwebview, cgrect

I would like to remove the side grey bars but I do not know how to do it. 
I tried many solutions like:

[image]

```
 self.webView.frame = self.view.bounds
 self.webView.scalesPageToFit = true
 webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
```

But nothing works...

EDIT: changing in white is better, but I would like to have a real fullscreen webview.
[image]

Comment: try this:  webView.contentMode = .aspectFill

Comment: can you add your webview http URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing your project using an **iPhone X** *(or similar)*, which has **top and bottom safe-area margins** *(or left and right margins in this case because you are using it in landscape mode)*.

You could use **AutoLayout** engine to setup your views layout, doing something like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    self.webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
    self.webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
    self.webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
    self.webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor)
]);
```

[Reference to Apple documentation about: "Adaptivity and Layout"](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/)

Answer (score 1):

you can change the CSS of the page to adapt to 100% width and 100% height of the web page.

```css
width:100%; height:100%; background-size:cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
webview.backgroundColor = .white
```

Comment: The problem is that it is just changing the colors, I put an example in my question.

Comment: @ΩlostA Add your URL so that we can check the issue. I think you are testing on iPhone X , landscape mode.